# Where can I download the Core Audio SDK for Xcode? (Not apple developer site it seems)

Tags: objective-c, sdk, core-audio

As per the instructions here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH3-SW1

It says:
The Core Audio SDK assumes you will use Xcode as your development environment.
You can download the latest SDK from http://developer.apple.com/sdk/. After installation, the SDK files are located in /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio.

I looked at all the SDKs and did a search for Core audio. Nothing shows up. Does anyone know where I can find the Core Audio SDKs?

Comment: PlayFile still exists. Not sure why some Apple support is so overlooked while other documentation is quite complete. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlayFile/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. Core Audio SDK is included with current Xcode 4.2. You need to link to it like this:

[image]

and of course include its header file.

Comment: @hooleyhoop is correct. For future reference, my answer is incorrect. Please disregard.

Answer (score 7):

The Core Audio framework is just a standard framework in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, so you already have the headers and libraries. The additional SDK stuff is now installed as part of the Xcode 4 installation - you'll find it at `/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio` after installing Xcode 4.

Answer (score 4):

The document you referred to is kinda old (written in 2007) and you've discovered that Apple isn't always super good at updating their documentation.

The Core Audio SDK has been folded into the SDK's for MacOS and iOS.

At least one of sample programs referenced on the instruction page, PlaySequence, can be [downloaded as sample code from Apple's developer website](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PlaySequence/).  I'm not sure what happened to PlayFile.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the CoreAudio SDK was renamed Core Audio Utility Classes, and can be found there:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html